# Insert <?php echo in <?php if

Tags: php, range, echo

```
<?php if($range == 'arizona'): ?>
    <?php echo $image->county; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Ok, so this code is working, and the echo output is : "arizona"

Now I would like to replace the 'arizona' on the first line, using the echo. I tried :

```
<?php if($range == $image->county;): ?>
    <?php echo $image->county; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But not working. How can I include :

```
    $image->county;
```

In the first line ?

Comment: increase the error output level in your php.conf so that you get error messages. The semicolon shouldn't be there.

Comment: The answers from Tim and j13r are correct. But in single-line PHP statements like these, you don't need _any_ trailing semicolons. My preference is to remove them all.

Comment: `var_dump($image->county )` whats the output ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from your `if` expression:

```
<?php if($range == $image->county): ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php if($range == $image->county){ ?>
   <?php echo $image->county; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You're close!** Just need to remove the semicolon from the first line:

```
<?php if($range == $image->county): ?>
    <?php echo $image->county; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also leave php open until the end of your code instead of opening and closing it on every line which can lead to poor readability.  Also, you had that extra semicolon in your first line.  ;D

```
<?php if($range == $image->county) {
    echo $image->county;
} ?>
```